# How do I load balance based on backend connections in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm trying to set up a hybrid cloud with AWS as the primary gateway.

To save money, I want to direct all traffic up to 1,000 connections to on-premise and the rest to AWS servers. How can I do that in a scalable manner in AWS?

As far as I can tell, neither Network or Application Load Balancers support this nor Target Groups. Only weigted or Least Outstanding Requests balancing.

Is there a name for this type of load balancing?